# BetterTouchTool: Is it possible to use a context-menu item with a gesture?

Tags: bettertouchtool

Example: I want to attach the "TipTap Left" gesture with "Save Image As..." from the context-menu in Chrome. Possible?

Answer (score 2):

The current version of BetterTouchTool has a `Trigger Context Menu Item` action in the list of Predefined Actions.

Comment: Yes, you can do this easily with current BTT; I've just verified this.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this in BetterTouchTool alone. The following steps use Keyboard Maestro specifically, but you should be able to duplicate them in some way with most any macro application.

1. Set the gesture in BTT to an unusual keyboard shortcut that won't be used by anything else.
   [image: BTT gesture]
2. In Keyboard Maestro, create a new macro that is triggered by this shortcut.
   [image: KM macro]
3. Set the contents of the macro as follows:

   - Move and Click at (0,0) from the Current Mouse Location
   - Insert Text ‘Save Image As’ by Typing
   - Type the Return Keystroke

   Here's [what it should look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQyYW.png)